# NoClassDefFoundError: roboguice.inject.ContextScopedRoboInjector on android 4.3 (Jelly Bean API 18)

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, roboguice

I have an app which is using roboguice 3 and it crashes on start on devices with API 18.
Same app works perfect on android 23.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: roboguice.inject.ContextScopedRoboInjector
01-12 16:53:31.285 12710-12710/com.package.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at roboguice.RoboGuice.getInjector(RoboGuice.java:197)
01-12 16:53:31.285 12710-12710/com.package.app  E/AndroidRuntime:     at roboguice.activity.RoboActionBarActivity.onCreate(RoboActionBarActivity.java:85)
```

any ideas?

Comment: I recommend using Toothpick instead. It's made by the same people who were maintaining Roboguice. Toothpick is as easy to use as Roboguice, but it's a lot faster. https://github.com/stephanenicolas/toothpick

Comment: I migrated to https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Comment: Roboguice does injection of classes, views and resources. Toothpick and Dagger inject classes. Butterknife injects views. So you can use Butterknife with either Dagger or Toothpick.

Comment: @Christine I migrated to ButterKnife and Dagger ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in their [GitHub page](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice)

```
RoboGuice is no longer supported.
[..]
There are now many other excellent DI frameworks for Android, please consider migrating to one of them.
```